# Extending NSDecimalNumber to conform to ExpressibleByStringLiteral crashes LLDB RPC server

Tags: swift, string-literals, swift-extensions

A playground contains only an extension of NSDecimalNumber that conforms it to ExpressibleByStringLiteral and a variable x that attempts to utilize that extension, and the LLDB RPC server crashes:

```swift
import Cocoa

extension NSDecimalNumber: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral value: Self.StringLiteralType) {
        self.init(string: value)
    }
}



let x: NSDecimalNumber = "1.2"
```

---

- Swift 3
- Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002)
- OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1421)

Filed on Apple Radar and OpenRadar: https://openradar.appspot.com/31556528

Answer (score 1):

While this is a bug of the compiler that should be reported, your extension is wrong on many levels.

1. `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` has two parent protocols that have to be implemented too.
2. You are not declaring the `typealias` for the protocol associated type (`StringLiteralType`).
3. You cannot use `Self.` outside protocol declaration.
4. The initializer would have to be `public`.
5. You can declare only `convenience` initializers in an extension, not designated initializers.
6. The only way to implement the initializer is using a `required` initializer inside the class definition.

In summary, you cannot declare conformance with this protocol in an extension.

Why this is a bad idea:

1. `NSDecimalNumber` initializer is locale dependendent. That means your code behavior would change depending on current locale.
2. In Swift we should use `Decimal` instead of `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between what the OP is proposing and what you're proposing.  Primarily, an `NSDecimalNumber` or `Decimal` can exactly represent "1.2" whereas going through a double, which cannot represent 1.2 exactly can result in different results.

Comment: @DavidBerry You are right, I was hoping for a better `Decimal` initialization but you are right it goes through floating point again.

Comment: Perhaps even more important `decimal = Decimal(string: "1.2")` yields different results from `decimal = Decimal(string: "1.20")`

Comment: @DavidBerry In my testing both return `12e-1`.

Comment: But one of them returns 3 digits of precision and one returns 2 :)  At least that's what I recall of the guts of `NSDecimalNumber`  Of course, the last time I used it was about a decade ago...